# Flutter display Image fullscreen, get offset and scale factor

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to display an image full screen on tablet and get new size and scale factor of image.

The scale factor and new size is needed so display additional information on image. I would like to display markers and other helpers, like screenshot.

[image]

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Image.network(
        'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/jmwAAOxy3NBSpNvN/s-l1600.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of a `Stack`, a  `Positioned.fill` and a `LayoutBuilder` to get the width and height of the image and then position your children accordingly. The width/height should be enough to determine the scale factor when you compare it to the original size.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/jmwAAOxy3NBSpNvN/s-l1600.jpg',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) {
                    // Do whatever you want here
                    return Text(constraints.toString());
                  }
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

https://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/XWmGrdo